# importing data and fitting survival model

Tags: object, import, stata, analysis, survival

I am trying to import data from Stata to R and fit a survival model. I did the following:

`library(haven)`
`data <- read_dta("C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.dta")`
`View(data)`
`install.packages(c("survival", "survminer"))`
`library("survival")`
`library("survminer")`

It worked well. However, I got errors:

```
data("data")
Warning message:
In data("data") : data set ‘data’ not found 

fit <- survfit(Surv(data$finaltime, data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI) , data = data)
Error in survfit.Surv(Surv(data$finaltime, data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI), data = data) : 
  the survfit function requires a formula as its first argument
```

I wonder if you can tell me how to fix this.

Comment: As in your previous thread, please note: 1. Your need for help and your gratitude if you get any  are taken as read, and don't need to be spelled out. 2. The spelling is Stata, not STATA.  Sorry, I don't use R and have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Also, if using R you should add `r` to your tags rather than generic tags like `analysis`. This will help elicit more attention from that community (as opposed to Stata users who happen to know some R)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you aren't supplying a formula. As noted in the documentation for `survfit` one must now supply a formula:

> Older releases of the code also allowed the specification for a
> single curve to omit the right hand of the formula, i.e.,
> survfit(Surv(time, status)), in which case the formula argument is not
> actually a formula. Handling this case required some non-standard and
> fairly fragile manipulations, and this case is no longer supported.

Here in an example of a fix, where `~ 1` would be replaced by the formula that fits your research question:

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(data$finaltime, data$GSTATUS_DTHCNS_KI) ~ 1 , data = data)
summary(fit)
```

See `help("survfit.formula")` for more information.